# Is is possible to add additional registrations to an existing WindsorContainer using XmlInterpreter?

Tags: castle-windsor

I'd like to be able to register some types on a container and then top these up with some additional type declared in an XML configuration file.  Unfortunately, IConfigurationInterpreter (implemented by XmlInterpreter) is only available in the WindsorContainer() constructor, not in any AddXXX() methods.  Is there any other way I can achieve this without resorting to parent/child containers (that may soon be unsupported).

Background: Our large application is only starting to use the Castle framework to register and resolve some of it's components. Because Castle is being retrofitted into this app we're using a singleton class to maintain a global instance of WindsorContainer(). In unit tests, we need to wire up this container instance to use a combination of custom mock implementations (specific to the test) + some default mock implementations. For DLL dependency reasons, these mock class types are unavailable in this unit test fixture abstract base class so dynamic registration (using strings) is necessary. I was hoping to use an XML resource file to register the default mocks. Otherwise I have to do the same using an IWindsorInstaller implementation that's really duplicating what XmlInterpreter does.  This API appears to be forcing this direction.

Answer (score 2):

I think these will work ...

container.Install(Castle.Windsor.Installer.Configuration.FromXml(resource))

OR

container.Install(Castle.Windsor.Installer.Configuration.FromXmlFile(path))

which both avoid use of the IConfigurationInterpreter interface.